# Magento Get Order Total In Pence Request

Tags: php, magento, payment, gateway

I am integrating a custom payment gateway into magento.

I need to send the order total to them in pence, currently it is set to pounds.

My current code is below

```
<?php
$_order = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order();
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
$_order->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
?>
<form name="mygatewayform" method="get" action="gateway url">
<input type="hidden" name="Tariff" value="<?php echo $_order->getBaseGrandTotal(); ?>">
</form>
```

This adds the total to the 'action' gateway URL as the Tariff but total is in pounds i.e. 1.50 but needs to be in pence 150.

Comment: Do you remove decimal and want to be number format?

Comment: I need to remove the decimal point yes, so for example price is 1.50 i need to send to them as 150 without any decimal point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="hidden" name="Tariff" value="<?php echo ceil($_order->getBaseGrandTotal() * 100); ?>">
```